# Google Maps V3 - Load different markers on click function

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

So I have the following in my HTML which represents regions in the UK:-

```
<h4 id="google-ne" class="active">The North East</h4>
<h4 id="google-nw">The North West</h4>
<h4 id="google-ea">East Anglia</h4>
<h4 id="google-em">East Midlands</h4>
<h4 id="google-tm">The Midlands</h4>
<h4 id="google-wm">West Midlands</h4>
<h4 id="google-ld">London</h4>
<h4 id="google-se">South East</h4>
<h4 id="google-sw">South West</h4>
<h4 id="google-ws">Wales</h4>
<h4 id="google-sl">Scotland</h4>
```

and then the marker lat / long and region are displayed in HTML as follows:-

```
<div class="marker" data-lat="52.559437" data-lng="-2.1493073" data-region="West Midlands"></div>
<div class="marker" data-lat="51.646145" data-lng="-0.45614472" data-region="South East"></div>
```

and so on, there are about 400 markers.

I am currently using the following code to display all markers on the map which is working fine:-

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5280359,-0.1304897);

function initialize_map() {  
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };     
    var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();     
    var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);

    var isDraggable = w > 480 ? true : false;
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: center,
    //draggable: isDraggable,
    //mapTypeControl: false,
    //draggable: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    scaleControl: true,
    scrollwheel: true,
    navigationControl: true,
    streetViewControl: true,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
    mapOptions);

    // Multiple Markers

// Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
$('.marker').each(function() {     
    var location = {
        latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(
            $( this ).data( 'lat' ),
            $( this ).data( 'lng' )
        ),
        //title: $( this ).find( 'h2' ).html()
    };

    new google.maps.Marker( {
        map: map,
        position: location.latLng,
        //title: $( this ).data( 'desc' )
    } );

    markerBounds.extend( location.latLng );
});

// Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    this.setZoom(14);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
});            

    var styles = [
        /* Black & White {"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#e9e9e9"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f5f5f5"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f5f5f5"},{"lightness":21}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#dedede"},{"lightness":21}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":36},{"color":"#333333"},{"lightness":40}]},{"elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#fefefe"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#fefefe"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]} */
        /* Colour*/ {"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":"-63"},{"lightness":"23"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.natural","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":"-100"},{"lightness":"25"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.natural.terrain","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":"0"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":"0"},{"color":"#95bf97"},{"lightness":"59"}]},{"featureType":"poi.school","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"lightness":"5"},{"hue":"#ff0000"},{"saturation":"-100"}]},{"featureType":"poi.sports_complex","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"lightness":"5"},{"saturation":"-100"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":"-85"},{"lightness":"12"}]}
    ];

map.setOptions({styles: styles});

}

initialize_map(); 

}
```

What I want to do now is on click of say 'West Midlands' `#google-wm`, it removes all markers currently on the map and then only shows markers where the `data-region` == 'West Midlands'

How is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your (map) markers to an array with the region. When you click on your DIV, loop through the markers array and do a `marker.setMap(null)` on all markers with a different region. This was asked here already many times...

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42008638/maps-api-markers-visible-true-false-of-a-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like that. Code is commented for the parts that I have added/changed.

```js
var markers = [];
var map;

function initialize() {

  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52, -1);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

  $('.marker').each(function() {
    var location = {
      latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(
        $(this).data('lat'),
        $(this).data('lng')
      ),
    };

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: location.latLng,
    });

    // Register click event
    $(this).on('click', function() {

      clickMarker($(this).data('region'));
    });

    // Push marker and region to markers array
    markers.push({
      'marker': marker,
      'region': $(this).data('region')
    });
  });
}

function clickMarker(region) {

  // Loop through markers array
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

    // If marker region = selected region, display it
    if (markers[i].region === region) {

      markers[i].marker.setMap(map);

    } else {

      // Hide marker from different region
      markers[i].marker.setMap(null);
    }
  }
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div class="marker" data-lat="52.5" data-lng="-2.1" data-region="West Midlands">Marker 1 - WM</div>
<div class="marker" data-lat="52.6" data-lng="-2.2" data-region="West Midlands">Marker 2 - WM</div>
<div class="marker" data-lat="51.6" data-lng="-0.4" data-region="South East">Marker 3 - SE</div>
<div class="marker" data-lat="51.7" data-lng="-0.5" data-region="South East">Marker 4 - SE</div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for!